# PHP error message

Tags: php

I am getting the following error when attempting to buy something in the shop at www.1dt.biz/shop.

I wondered if you could point me in the right direction on how I could fix it?

```
Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in /home/1dt/web/shop/includes/functions/general.php on line 1090

Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in /home/1dt/web/shop/includes/functions/general.php on line 1090

Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in /home/1dt/web/shop/includes/functions/general.php on line 1090

Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in /home/1dt/web/shop/includes/functions/general.php on line 1090

Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in /home/1dt/web/shop/includes/functions/general.php on line 1090

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/1dt/web/shop/includes/functions/general.php:1090) in /home/1dt/web/shop/includes/functions/general.php on line 33
```

Comment: Really? Just don't use `eregi()` anymore (its deprecated for years now!). Use `preg_*()`. See the php manual

Comment: @davidt, did you even read the error message?

Answer (score 8):

Assuming the site is yours, you should stop using `eregi` as it's deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `eregi`, and that is deprecated (as the warning says)

The last warning is because the warnings allready send a header you can't send another one

best option: replace eregi with a preg variant: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

second best option: set `error_reporting` to something that doesn't show the deprecated errors. (`error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);` or something like that.)

Comment: Many thanks for your help, I will get on to it, is there a reason why these errors have just started to appear? The site was recently hacked could that have anything to do with it?

Comment: Well, as you can read over at the manual (http://php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php) the function was deprecated since 5.3.0, so the most likely explanation is that your php-version was updated. Maybe it was updated after the hack by the sysadmin?

Answer (score 1):

Use preg_match http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 1):

you can use `@eregi()` to suppress warnings from that call.

or use `preg_match` instead, because `eregi` is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

eregi() was deprecated in PHP 5.3 you either need to replace that call with preg_match() or change your warnings to ignore deprecated functions (not recommended).

Answer (score 1):

You should use `preg_match`, because `eregi` is deprecated and will be removed

Answer (score 0):

The following warning is caused by a header change attempt after it is too late (i.e. you have already echo'd, etc):

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/1dt/web/shop/includes/functions/general.php:1090) in /home/1dt/web/shop/includes/functions/general.php on line 33
```

The depreciation warning is obvious and answered a bunch already here.